# Why CoreData make entity fault after save?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My steps:

1. Create entity via `.init(context: NSManagedObjectContext)`
2. Save context if it has changes. Save is succeded.
3. Use this entity to set some values. Example: `let newString = "test == \(entity.id.intValue)"`

The problem that after step 2 the id value of the entity time to time become 0.

I did debug and there are two types of output:

1. `<Entity: 0x60000023def0> (entity: Entity; id: 0x600002777d40 <x-coredata:///UserEntity/tC5203E3F-0F4A-4937-B44A-45CD578382AA10>; data: <fault>)`
2. `<Entity: 0x6000003c9f40> (entity: Entity; id: 0xab5e4a90b6dee4ba <x-coredata://3EC29A9F-A81A-49EC-B4BE-23004ECF10FF/UserEntity/p88>; data: { ...has data }`

Also in the first situation `isFault` is `true`, is second it is `false`.

I can't understand why saving of the context can make entities fault?

Comment: Why are you even creating the Entity this way? Isnt it just much more convenient to do that in your apps entities folder?

Comment: @AisultanAskarov don't understand what you mean under "apps entities folder".

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the bug is probably somewhere in your code which you are NOT showing in your question. That is why I am just going to give you the function to fetch the value in the entity. If the code I post wont help then perhaps its the timing issue.

```
static let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
  
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "YOUR_APPs_NAME")
container.loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
  if let error = error as NSError? {
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }
}

static var context: NSManagedObjectContext { return persistentContainer.viewContext }

func loadUserIsVerified() -> Id {
    
    var id : Id!
    let context = CoreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest< Id > = Id.fetchRequest()
    
    do {
        let ids = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if(sessions.count > 0) {
            id = ids.first
        }
    } catch {
        print("Something happened while trying to retrieve tasks...")
    }
    return id
}
```

Comment: This code make a fetch request, but I don't fetch entity. I just create in on my context!